# How To Merge two dictionaries using kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I hope that I'm able to phrase this question properly as I am very new to kusto. Basically I am trying to write a kusto query that returns a dictionary where certain requirements are met. I have a table with several columns(Name, External, Parent) the goal is to return a dictioanary where key: Name , value: Parent. However there are some instances where the "Parent" column is blank, when this is true the value instead needs to be: value:External. Currently I have a query that returns two dictionaries in seperate rows, but I wanted to know if it is possible to have them all in one dictionary. I hope I explained this well, code is below:

```
let Query1 = view () {
cluster('mycluster').database('my_database').Sizes
|distinct Name, Size, External
|where isempty( Size)| extend p = pack(Name, External) 
|summarize dict=make_bag(p)};
let Query2 = view (){
cluster('mycluster').database('my_database').Sizes
|distinct Name, Size, External
|where not(isempty( Size))| extend o = pack(Name, Parent) 
|summarize dict=make_bag(o)};
union withsource="TempTableName" Query1, Query2
```

code returns:

| TempTableName | dict |
| --- | --- |
| Query1 | {B0: Standard, B12: Standard1, B13: Standard5 |
| Query2 | {B1:Basic0, B5: Basic09, B19: Basic12} |

Comment: This code is erroneous. You use `distinct Name, Size, External` and then you refer to `Parent`, and In any case, the `distinct` doesn't seem to make any sense. I seriously doubt if there is a need for `union` here/ Please share a data sample.

Comment: Sorry about that! I as changing around variables and forgot to update a couple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `bag_merge()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-merge-function

```
print d1 = dynamic({"B0": "Standard", "B12": "Standard1", "B13": "Standard5"}),
      d2 = dynamic({"B1":"Basic0", "B5": "Basic09", "B19": "Basic12"})
| project d3 = bag_merge(d1, d2)
```

| d3 |
| --- |
| { "B0": "Standard", "B12": "Standard1", "B13": "Standard5", "B1": "Basic0", "B5": "Basic09", "B19": "Basic12" } |

or, with your query:

```
let d1 = toscalar(
    cluster('mycluster').database('my_database').Sizes
    | distinct Name, Size, External
    | where isempty(Size)
    | extend p = pack(Name, External) 
    | summarize dict=make_bag(p)
);
let d2 = toscalar(
    cluster('mycluster').database('my_database').Sizes
    | distinct Name, Size, External
    | where not(isempty(Size))
    | extend o = pack(Name, Parent) 
    | summarize dict=make_bag(o)
);
print d = bag_merge(d1, d2)
```